# Django tutorial. from . import views

Tags: python, django, python-import

I started to learn Django, I don't know python very well, so please forgive me, if the question is quite stupid).

`from . import views`

what is "." in this statement? Module's name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The single dot is a convention from command line applications. It means the current directory. In terms of Django it stands for the directory/module the current file is on.

Comment: Why not just say `import views` without the `from .`? Is there another system module with the same name somewhere else?

Comment: @jonjavak Probably no, and many apps prefer to import from a custom namespace (e.g &quot;django&quot;).  It&#39;s a small convention that makes things slightly easier to debug

Answer (score 4):

As others explained `.` refers to the current directory (or module / package) of the file that you are currently viewing.

The imports that use this syntax are called ***relative imports***.

[PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) describes how relative imports came about and what specific syntax was chosen. The idea behind it was to use periods to determine how to relatively import other packages / modules. The reason was to prevent the accidental shadowing of standard library modules.

Answer (score 1):

It means from the current directory import `views.py` module

Answer (score 1):

while one dot means the current directory if you want upper dicrectory then use double dot just for your referencce